# How can I check or fix broken hardware links? "mount: no such device"

Tags: mount, usb, solaris

I have a SunBlade1000 running SunOS5.8 and I have a usb cradle from StarTech.com attached to it with a 1TB and a 2TB HDD from Seagate.

The 1TB mounted just fine and is currently being written to. The 2TB drive was connected to the computer all last year but now for some reason doesn't want to connect to the Sunblade. A read-only analyze test in format -e works which shows the drive is talking to the computer, however when I try to mount using mount it returns a strange error:

```
# mount /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s2 /home/data/usb2
mount: /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s2 no such device
```

I've read the error manual on the Oracle website and it recommended checking out /devices to check for broken links. I've compared the links from the inactive drive to the one that works and they look (almost) identical. The drive that works is located at `/devices/pci@8,700000/usb5,3/hub@4/storage@2/disk@0,0:c`  and the one that doesn't is located at `/devices/pci@8,700000/usb5,3/hub@4/storage@3/disk@0,0:c`. Storage@2 and storage@3 are similarly populated and at this point, I am stuck.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this drive working again without risking the data stored on the disk?

EDIT 6/7/15:
I ran the read-only analysis by using the format utility (format -e -> analyze -> read) The analysis never actually finished (ran for a little over a week and then the computer crashed under mysterious circumstances) but looking at the configuration for the read-test you can see that it should have fixed any defective blocks upon finding them:

> analyze> config
>         Analyze entire disk? yes
>         Loop continuously? no
>          Number of passes: 2
>          Repair defective blocks? yes
>          Stop after first error? no
>          Use random bit patterns? no
>          Number of blocks per transfer: 126 (0/2/0)
>          Verify media after formatting? yes
>          Enable extended messages? no
>          Restore defect list? yes
>          Restore disk label? yes

EDIT 6/8/15:

```
# ls -la /dev/dsk/c4t0d0*

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          61 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s0 -> 
../../devices/pci@8,700000/usb@5,3/hub@4/storage@3/disk@0,0:a

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          61 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s1 -> 
../../devices/pci@8,700000/usb@5,3/hub@4/storage@3/disk@0,0:b

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          61 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s2 -> 
../../devices/pci@8,700000/usb@5,3/hub@4/storage@3/disk@0,0:c

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          61 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s3 -> 
../../devices/pci@8,700000/usb@5,3/hub@4/storage@3/disk@0,0:d

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          61 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s4 -> 
../../devices/pci@8,700000/usb@5,3/hub@4/storage@3/disk@0,0:e

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          61 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s5 -> 
../../devices/pci@8,700000/usb@5,3/hub@4/storage@3/disk@0,0:f

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          61 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s6 -> 
../../devices/pci@8,700000/usb@5,3/hub@4/storage@3/disk@0,0:g

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          61 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s7 -> 
../../devices/pci@8,700000/usb@5,3/hub@4/storage@3/disk@0,0:h

# ls -laL /dev/dsk/c4t0d0*
brw-------   1 root     sys      253, 40 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s0
brw-------   1 root     sys      253, 41 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s1
brw-------   1 root     sys      253, 42 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s2
brw-------   1 root     sys      253, 43 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s3
brw-------   1 root     sys      253, 44 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s4
brw-------   1 root     sys      253, 45 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s5
brw-------   1 root     sys      253, 46 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s6
brw-------   1 root     sys      253, 47 Dec 31  1999 /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s7
```

EDIT 6/9/15
The dsk contents point to the correct addresses and rdsk points to their raw counterparts.

I restored the backup label and tried remounting but that didn't seem to help.

for those who wanted to see what it looks like when I select the disk:

```
# format -e  
Searching for disks...done  


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:  
       0. c1t1d0 <SUN18G cyl 7506 alt 2 hd 19 sec 248>  
          /pci@8,600000/SUNW,qlc@4/fp@0,0/ssd@w2100002037f071f3,0  
       1. c4t0d0 <Seagate cyl 65535 alt 2 hd 511 sec 63>  
          /pci@8,700000/usb@5,3/hub@4/storage@3/disk@0,0  
       2. c6t0d0 <drive type unknown>  
          /pci@8,700000/usb@5,3/hub@4/storage@2/disk@0,0  
Specify disk (enter its number): 1  
selecting c4t0d0  
[disk formatted]  


FORMAT MENU:  
        disk       - select a disk  
        type       - select (define) a disk type  
        partition  - select (define) a partition table  
        current    - describe the current disk  
        format     - format and analyze the disk  
        repair     - repair a defective sector  
        label      - write label to the disk  
        analyze    - surface analysis  
        defect     - defect list management  
        backup     - search for backup labels  
        verify     - read and display labels  
        save       - save new disk/partition definitions  
        inquiry    - show vendor, product and revision  
        scsi       - independent SCSI mode selects  
        cache      - enable, disable or query SCSI disk cache  
        volname    - set 8-character volume name  
        !<cmd>     - execute <cmd>, then return  
        quit  
    format>
```

Comment: Amend question to show us how you did the analysis test. Also rerun the test (exactly what you post here in the question).

Comment: I'll restart the read-only test tomorrow, but it will be a long time before it's finished analyzing the 2TB disk

Comment: I can not see in your running of format, where you specify the disk.

Comment: What's the output from `ls -la /dev/dsk/c4t0d0*` and `ls -laL /dev/dsk/c4t0d0*`?

Comment: In `format` you gave, c4t0d0  Seagate cyl 65535 alt 2 hd 511 sec 63   is a 1 TB disk. the 2TB disk looks to be missing, but in any case it should be adressed by c6t0d0s2, haven't you swap disks ?

Comment: Try running `devfsadm -C`, then `devfsadm`. Also, don't use slice `s2` to hold any data, that's reserved for the whole disk.